# $\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}(x)=0$ has atleast one root in $x \in (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{4}{5})$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let the function $f(x)$ be thrice differentiable and satisfies $f(f(x))=1-x$ for $x \in [0,1]$ , and given that $\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}(\frac{4}{5})=0 $
.
We have to prove that $\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}=0$ has atleast one root in $x \in (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{4}{5} ) $.  What I simplified is $f(x)+f(1-x)=1 $
. By differentiating it twice we get $\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}(\frac{1}{2})=0$
. But still I am unable to prove the given condition

Answer (score 1):

It would be interesting to know the context of this problem (I mean was this an exercise problem in some text?). I do not know the answer to this question. However, I can tell you that you might be in a wrong direction. In arriving at the conclusion $f(x) + f(1-x) =1$, I guess your argument had gone in the following way:
$$f(1-x) = f(f(f(x))) = 1-f(x).$$ This assumes that $f(x) \in [0,1]$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. We have $$f^{\prime}(f(x)) f^{\prime}(x) = -1, \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
where $f^{\prime}(x) = \frac{df}{dx}$. Equation \eqref{eq1} implies that $f^{\prime}(x)$ is never $0$ in $[0,1]$. Since $f^{\prime}(x)$ is continuous, it follows that $f^{\prime}(x)$ should be either less than $0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ or should be greater than $0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. In any case $f$ is monotonic. Without loss of generality, we shall assume that $f(x)$ is strictly increasing on $[0,1]$. Now from the function equation $f(f(x)) = 1-x$, $f(f(0)) = 1$ and $f(f(1)) =0$. This implies that range of $f(x)$ is $[0,1]$. Since $f$ is increasing, it should happen that $f(0) =0$ and $f(1) = 1$. But then $$1- 0 = f(f(0)) = f(0) = 0, $$ which is a contradiction. Hence our assumption that $f(x) \in [0,1]$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ is not true. That means, your equation $f(x) + f(1-x) = 1$ is not true for all $x\in [0,1]$. What can only be said  is that
$$ f(f(x)) + f(f(1-x)) = 1$$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.